# Unique fixed point on $[0, 2\pi ]$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

In the following question I am looking for an explanation of the answer which is given. How did they find the critical point?

> Prove that $f(x) = \pi + \frac{1}{2}\sin \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)$ has a unique fixed point on $[0,2 \pi]$

Checking the range of the function $f$:

we have that $f(0) = \pi $ and $f(2\pi ) = \pi$.

The derivative of $f(x)$ is:

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{4} \cos \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)$$.

Here is what I am having trouble understanding. The only critical point inside the interval is at $x = \pi$. How did they find this critical point? Do I then take that critical point evaluate the function at it and conldude that $0 \leq f(x) \leq 2\pi$ for all $x \in [0, 2\pi]$ and thus a fixed point exists?

Comment: To find the critical point see when $f'(x)=0$ for $x\in[0,2\pi]$

Comment: so then it is only 0 when x is $\pi$? making $\cos(\pi /2) = 0$?

Comment: Yes. Since here $x\in[0,2\pi]$. But in general when restriction on $x$ is not given then $f'(x)=0$ for $x=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$. You can use [Banach fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) to prove it has a fixed point.

Comment: and then do I take this critical point evaluate it at the function and conclude that $0 \leq f(x) \leq 2\pi $ for all x on the interval $[0, 2\pi]$?

Comment: Yes, the critical point is were function reaches maximum or minimum so find $f(x)$ at that point and see if the inequality holds. You've already checked both ends of the interval.

Comment: okay I think that answers my question in the last comment

Comment: and then because the absolute value of the derivative is always less then 1 it is unique? in this case it is always less then 1/4

Comment: but then why am I checking the range of the problem in the first step?

Comment: @Vasya why would I check the range in the first step?

Comment: @fr14: you need to check both ends of the interval. Critical point is where function changes behavior. If it was increasing and started decreasing, you have a local maximum but it is possible for global maximum to be different if $f(a)$ or $f(b)$ are larger.

Comment: @Vasya could I of just checked the absolute minima and absolute maxima on the interval, concluded that it was still on the interval and therefore the function exists

Comment: and checking where the derivative is 0 to see if that's on the interval too

Comment: Yes, you can do this if function is continuous.

Comment: but checking it at 2pi wouldn't give me the maxima the maxima is at pi so I wouldn't be able to use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that $f(0)=\pi$, $f(\pi)=\pi+0.5$, $f(2\pi)=\pi$. According to intermediate value theorem, $\pi \le f(x) \le \pi+0.5$ when $0 \le x \le \pi$. We cannot have fixed point there. On the other hand, $\pi \le f(x) \le \pi+0.5$ when $\pi \le x \le 2\pi$. Because there are no critical points between $\pi$ and $2\pi$, we know that $x=f(x)$ has only one solution on this interval.

Comment: does your max and min give you your critical point for $f'(x)$ here our max and min is pi and that is what makes $f'(x) =0$

Comment: @fr14: maximum is actually $\pi+0.5$. To find critical points you find where $f'(x)=0$. But because you have the same value at both ends, you know that the function either constant or has a critical point.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why you are checking for critical points.

Note that $\sup_x |f'(x)| = {1 \over 4} < 1 $, and $f([0,2 \pi]) \subset [0, 2 \pi]$.

Hence $f$ is a contraction map and has a unique fixed point.